# Transparent become black when using shearImage function in php

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to skew the image using php Imagick and like this

```
$image->shearImage("transparent", 0, $y);
```

In the example below there are four images, and the two is skewed

When doing in my laptop, WSL Ubuntu 16.04, php7.4 it will successfully skew the image and is transparent background. like this

[image]

but doing the same in digitalOcean Ubuntu 18.04, php 7.4, it becomes black like this

[image]

Why is that, is anyone have the same problem? And how did you fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

> Imagick::setImageVirtualPixelMethod — Sets the image virtual pixel
>   method

[setImageVirtualPixelMethod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagevirtualpixelmethod.php)

Basically it specifys what happens to the background during a transform